# mvc6 controller action not called when using IOptions service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In an aspnet5/mvc6 project I use the configuration  builder to read the settings from appsettings.json:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

However, when I try to access the service from a controller, the action is not being called:

```
public IActionResult Index(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
   return View();
}
```

If I remove the appSettings parameter the action is being called correctly.
I don't get an error message. Do I need additional packages? Currently I'm using the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
```

Comment: Action parameters are getting filled using Model-Binding process (as they're representing data that is being sent by the client) and not by the environment configuration. You better inject `IOption<AppSettings>` in the controller constructor instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to inject your options through the action parameters, you need to decorate your options parameter with `[FromServices]`:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromServices] IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
   return View();
}
```

Though it's definitely supported, it's usually better to use constructor injection, as suggested by haim770.

Answer (score 1):

Like haim770 commented I needed to inject IOption in the controller constructor.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```